# How does adding 5 to 0FBh in an 8-bit register sets the Zero flag?

Tags: assembly

> adding 5 to 0FBh in an 8-bit register sets the Zero flag

I'm new so if you are an expert, please be patient with me.
Here is how I broke it down but I'm clearly doing something wrong. Perhaps my understanding of a zero flag is wrong?

In my understanding, the zero flag is set if the result is 0. 
0FB = 251; 
251 + 5 = 256; 
In binary:0000000100000000
In hexadecimal: 100

Which is not 0, so why is the zero flag set?

Comment: How many bits do you need to represent `256` in unsigned binary notation?

Comment: You have binary & hexadecimal swapped, and, as @EOF cleverly points out, your register only has room for 8 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest unsigned value you can store in an 8-bit register is `0xFF` (ie: `255` in base ten), so the value in the register is just plain zero (`0b00000000`), which causes **`ZF`** to be set.

Check the <strike>overflow</strike> carry flag, **`CF`**. It should be set too by this operation. You're doing an operation that causes the register value to be zero (**`+ZF`**) and the register to overflow (**`+CF`**).

Thanks to [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof) for pointing out the error in my post.

Comment: On most architectures I'm aware of, `OF` is set by overflow from the second-highest bit, not the highest. The flag relevant for unsigned overflow is the *carry flag*.

Comment: thanks . So what I'm understanding is that 256 is to large to be contained in the 8 bit register (as 255 is the least it can contain). In that case, where does it go? Does it transfer itself to a larger bit register?

Comment: Since 251 is -5 signed, and adding 5 to it is zero there is no overflow (OF=0). The carry flag (CF) should be set since 251+5 (unsigned) does carry out of bit 7.

Comment: @rose. It doesn't transfer to a larger bit register but it will set the carry flag. If you want to carry that into another register you can use the `adc` instruction after the `add`.

Comment: @EOF D'oh. Thanks for the catch there. I originally wrote carry flag, but couldn't remember and mis-corrected myself.

Comment: @DevNull: Well, to be fair this stuff can be confusing. Case in point: My comment to you is actually erroneous, the `OF` is usually set as the `xor` of the carry from the highest bit and the carry from the second-highest bit.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial / guide on [unsigned carry vs. signed overflow](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).  I added it to the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) a while ago, see the tag wiki for other nice guides, @rose.